# Import data to qweb report odoo

Tags: report, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I'm creating a simple odoo qweb report to display some records in the database. Up to now I can create a report with some static content(hardcoded).But I want to connect my template with the table in my database. My table is Faculty. Here is my template file

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <openerp>
  <data>
    <template id="ums_faculty_report">
        <div class="page">
            <h2>Report title</h2>
            <p>This is the description</p>

            <!-- 
            In here i want to display the list of data-
            <t t-foreach="dbrecords" t-as="o">
                <p><t t-esc="i"/></p>
            </t>
           ->
        </div>
    </template>
 </data>
</openerp>`
```

And this is my report.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
    <report
        id="ums.faculty_report"
        model="ums.faculty"
        string="All Faculties"
        report_type="qweb-pdf"
        name="ums.ums_faculty_report"
        attachment_use="False"
    />
  </data>
```

Simply I will repeat my problem again, I want to know how to bind a model to dbrecords in figure 1.Thanks in advance